# sign and trust gpg key automatically via bash

Tags: bash, gpg

I've got a question about gpg and signing a key automatically via bash:
I've got a script, that is doing the beginning of signing:

```
gpg --recv $schluessel1
gpg --edit $schluessel1
```

If I try something like this:

```
lsign
```

it is ignored and just show me the below output.

```
gpg>
```

From the above prompt, I can write manually `lsign` and later `y` in.

Is it possible to do these two steps automatically?

Comment: The phrase "sign and trust a gpg key automatically" just nearly gave me a coronary.

Comment: @Shadur Then I hope you don't use Enigmail...

Comment: @Shadur There are circumstances where it's appropriate. For example when you just generated the key.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script which does something similar (German but that seems not to be a problem here: http://www.openpgp-schulungen.de/scripte/keygeneration/key-generation.sh):

```
echo addkey$'\n'8$'\n'e$'\n'q$'\n'${length}$'\n'"$expire"$'\n'save$'\n' |
  LC_ALL= LANGUAGE=en gpg --batch --display-charset utf-8 --utf8-strings \
  --passphrase "$PASSPHRASE" --command-fd 0 --edit-key $x_short_id
```

This works with both GnuPG 1.4.x and 2.0.x.

With 1.4.x the `lsign` operation should be easily possible in a similar way. With 2.0.x you have to care about `gpg-agent`, too. That is possible but I have not implemented that yet. The basic idea is:

1. Start `gpg-agent` with a configuration which replaces `pinentry`.
2. Use a `pinentry` replacement which reads the necessary data from a FIFO (because the script is started by `gpg-agent`).
3. Start a background process which writes the necessary data to the FIFO.

Code example:

```
echo "OK - what's up?"
while read cmd rest; do
        # echo "cmd=$cmd rest=$rest" >&2
        : ${PINENTRY_USER_DATA}
        case "$cmd" in
                \#*)
                        :
                ;;
                GETINFO)
                        if [ "pid" = "$rest" ]; then
                                echo "D $$"
                        fi
                        echo "OK"
                ;;
                GETPIN)
                        read PASSPHRASE <"$input_fifo_path"
                        echo "D ${PASSPHRASE}"
                        echo "OK"
                ;;
                BYE)
                        echo "OK"
                        exit 0
                ;;
                *)
                        echo "OK"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the correct answer:

```
gpg --recv $key                     # receive Key from Keyserver
xdotool key y; xdotool key Return   # press y and then return
gpg --edit $key lsign save          # Sign and save the key
```

First I had to install xdotool `sudo apt-get install xdotool` then it was possible to run it automatically. By now I didn't try the save but hope it is just fine.